# Trigger Old Context Variables (oldMap, old)

Tags: apex, trigger

According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm), `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.oldMap` are only available in `update` and `delete` Triggers.

Are these variables `null` otherwise, or are they just empty? Would `Trigger.old.isEmpty()` return `true` if it's referenced in an `insert` Trigger?

Comment: easy to test ..

Comment: true, but documented no where..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trigger.Old is null in a Before Trigger and will therefore throw a NullPointerException for any reference / method invocation on it.

> 16:08:40.060 (60355000)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|********** Trigger.old null
>   16:08:40.060 (60362000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[2]|System.debug(ANY)
>   16:08:40.060 (60503000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object

Answer (score 15):

### Trigger

```
trigger LogTriggerOld on Account (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) 
{
    String BeforeOrAfter = (Trigger.isBefore ? 'Before' : 'After');

    String TriggerType = ''
        + (Trigger.isDelete ? 'Delete' : '')
        + (Trigger.isInsert ? 'Insert' : '')
        + (Trigger.isUpdate ? 'Update' : '')
        + (Trigger.isUnDelete ? 'UnDelete' : '');

    system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType 
        + ': ' + 'Trigger.old == null    ~ ' + (Trigger.old == null));

    system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType 
        + ': ' + 'Trigger.oldMap == null ~ ' + (Trigger.old == null));
}
```

### Test

```
@IsTest
public class TestTriggerOld {
    public static testmethod void InsertUpdateDeleteUndelete() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test 1'); insert a;
        a.Name = 'Test 2'; update a;
        delete a;
        undelete a;
    }
}
```

### Log results

```
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|After Insert: Trigger.old == null    ~ true
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|After Insert: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ true
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|After Update: Trigger.old == null    ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|After Update: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|After Delete: Trigger.old == null    ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|After Delete: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|After UnDelete: Trigger.old == null    ~ true
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|After UnDelete: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ true

USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Before Insert: Trigger.old == null    ~ true
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|Before Insert: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ true
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Before Update: Trigger.old == null    ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|Before Update: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Before Delete: Trigger.old == null    ~ false
USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|Before Delete: Trigger.oldMap == null ~ false
```

Answer (score 0):

The above test has a mistake in case it was run as it is written here
The second System.debug should print result of Trigger.oldMap, but instead it prints Trigger.old. 
I am not sure if it will change the result, but for the clearance of test should run it correctly :)

```
    trigger LogTriggerOld on Account (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) 
    {
String BeforeOrAfter = (Trigger.isBefore ? 'Before' : 'After');

String TriggerType = ''
    + (Trigger.isDelete ? 'Delete' : '')
    + (Trigger.isInsert ? 'Insert' : '')
    + (Trigger.isUpdate ? 'Update' : '')
    + (Trigger.isUnDelete ? 'UnDelete' : '');

system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType 
    + ': ' + 'Trigger.old == null    ~ ' + (Trigger.old == null));

system.debug(BeforeOrAfter + ' ' + TriggerType 
    + ': ' + 'Trigger.oldMap == null ~ ' + (Trigger.oldMap == null));
```

}